# pass parameters from java to groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a groovy script like:

```groovy
import groovy.sql.Sql

Object execute(def params = null) {

    def sql = new DBUtils().getConnection()

    println "sql params : " + params

    ...
}
```

And the java class will call this script like:

```java
Class scriptClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass( new File(url) ) ;

Object scriptInstance = scriptClass.newInstance() ;

String param = {"test"};

Object obj = scriptClass.getDeclaredMethod("execute", new Class[] {})
    .invoke( scriptInstance, new Object[] {param}  ) ;
```

I've tried various format arguments but none of them work. The above sample will throw the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments`

Any thoughts? appreciated.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the arguments' type properly, it should be:

```
String param = "test";
Object obj = scriptClass.getDeclaredMethod("execute", new Class[]{Object.class})
    .invoke(scriptInstance, new Object[]{param});
```

Indeed, if you call `getDeclaredMethod("execute", new Class[]{})`, you will get a method `execute` with **no argument** so it is not compatible with an `invoke` using an argument as you are trying to do.